# ASP.NET Core: Many routes -> always only one controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Similar to SO [ASP.NET MVC: Many routes -> always only one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863984/asp-net-mvc-many-routes-always-only-one-controller):

O have a .net 4.7 MVC project project

my config route are as follows (following from the above post)

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AllRoutes",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new
    {
      controller = "base",
    });
```

my base controller in my .net 4.7 project

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IHttpActionResult Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    return Ok();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    return Ok();
  }

  [HttpPut]
  public IHttpActionResult Put(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    return Ok();
  }

  [HttpDelete]
  public IHttpActionResult Delete(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    return Ok();
  }
}
```

now I'm porting my project into a .NET Core 2.0

I can't seem to setup the same thing

my config in the .net core project is as follows

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "AllRoutes",
      template: "{*url}",
      defaults: new
      {
        controller = "Base"
      }
    );
```

my base controller for my .net core project

```
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    return Ok("get success");
  }

  // POST api/values
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
  {
    return Ok("post success");
  }

  [HttpPut]
  public IActionResult Put([FromBody]string value)
  {
    return Ok("put success");
  }

  [HttpDelete]
  public IActionResult Delete()
  {
    return Ok("delete success");
  }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to slap a `[Route("/")]` onto the controller to make this work without having you to configure any MVC routing rules up front.

Comment: i'm needed to setup the routes dynamically as it requires to read some config file, so certain url goes to 1 controller and others to another

Answer (score 3):

Why do you even want to use MVC, when you have no controllers or routes?

Just use a custom middleware:

```
// Startup configure
app.Use(async (context, next) => 
{
    var service = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredServce<MyService>();
    var service.Execute();

    async next();
});
```

#### Update

Just in case it's not clear, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in your service, where you can directly access the request stream and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: how do you use the above code i'm not following?

basically i needed to setup the routes dynamically as it requires to read some config file, so certain url goes to 1 controller and others to another –

Comment: Your example above **doesn't have any routes** at all, just a general slug route. That's same as if you don't use routing middleware at all. You can remove all the controllers (which is just a single one in your case) and directly use `HttpContext` and the request within it to read the data, including the requested path `HttpContext.Request.Path` iirc. There is no need to have the overhead of the routing middleware, when you are not using routes at all

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BaseContoller : Controller {

[HttpGet("/base/get")]
public IActionResult Get() {
  return Ok("get success");
}
[HttpPost("/base/post")]
public IActionResult Post() {
return Ok("post success");
}
}
```

you looking for something like this?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, i'm after eg...

    http ://someurl/api/person -> goes to basecontroller
    http ://someurl/api/organisation -> goes to basecontroller
etc....

Answer (score -1):

or if you want to route this links you need add something like this

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
[Route("/get")]
public IActionResult Get() {
return Ok("get success");
}
}
```